# Can't Install Xcode 4.6.2 on OS X Mavericks

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-mavericks

I am unable to install Xcode 4.6.2 on OS X Mavericks. I upgraded from Mountain lion to OS X Mavericks and it was running during that time. I uninstalled it because i thought it was behaving in a strange manner and when i tried to re-install i got the error " Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because the version of OS X is too new.".

Looked up this error online and people recommended clearing cache but that didn't help.

Followed the  step on
 [Apple's Site](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/) but that didn't solve the problem either.

Not sure why its happening.

Comment: That's weird, I upgraded to Mavericks the other day and xcode 4.6.2 still works after the update.

Comment: Yup as i mentioned i was able to use as well until i uninstalled and tried to reinstall it

Comment: I also had this problem. If you download xcode 4.6.2 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads you can install it using the dmg file.

Comment: You can still get Xcode 4.6.3 from Apple Developer Downloads (back online now) and install from the DMG. Despite that App Store does not allow you to install it, it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Looks like it was a localized issue with my own Xcode and Mavericks. Upgrading to 5 fixed it for me, but it appears to not work for others.

Comment: Thanks i am already using Xcode 5 but i would not say its not compatible with OS X Mavericks because i was using Xcode 4.6.2 on OS X Mavericks until i uninstalled and tried to re-install it. Also on the app store it says compatible with OS X 10.7.4 and up

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/omz/ColorSense-for-Xcode/issues/19) on Github which proves that Xcode 4.6.3 can run on mavericks. If this helps.

Comment: I run XCode 4.6.3 on Mavericks without any Problems. Just download the DMG from the Developer Portal and install it the usual way.

Comment: xcode 4.6.3 is compatible with mavericks